# Android App crashing on setText

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and my code is not working how it should. The following does not update the text I have in a string called otp1. I think it is firing the exception, is there a way to see if it is? Also, any tips on why it is not working would be great.

```
package com.josephflynn.HelloWorld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.otp1);
            textViewToChange.setText("otp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/otp1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add this clickable button!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a valid view ID here:

```
findViewById(R.string.otp1)
```

Did you mean to do this?

```
findViewById(R.id.otp1)
```

If you can't figure it out, post your layout too. If you're trying to see the exception, get rid of that try/catch. Then after it crashes, look in LogCat (Window -> Show View -> LogCat).

Comment: If I change it to id I get 'id cannot be resolved or is not a field'.

Comment: Think I've fixed it by adding android:id="@+id/otp1" in the main.xml file. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Actually. That has fixed the id not resolving but the app is not changing the text still.

Comment: Post your actual updated code and tell us what's wrong now then? Is it crashing? Is it not crashing but the text doesn't change? What's happening?

Comment: I've fixed it. I made it change the text on clicking a button and that seemed to work. Thanks for your help.